# How to find trailing commas in javascript ExtJs or AngularJs code

Tags: javascript, regex, extjs, extjs4

I need to find trailing commas in my code if any for example:

```
id:"1",
name:"myComponent",
onClick:"someFunction",
listner:"someListner",
```

Now the last trailing comma in listener fails my ExtJS 4.2.2 script in IE 8. Is there a way or any regular expression to find such trailing commas.

Comment: If you only want to search object literals, you could do `,[ \t\n]*?\}`. This will find any commas before the closing }

Comment: If you use Sencha CMD, you see the warnings while building the app

Comment: @DarinKolev  Any other way to remove all trailing comma in ExtJS hole application using Sencha CMD or we have to do manually in all files.

Comment: @ Naresh below Answer helped me given by @Vikram Singh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open notepad ++ and in find menu select regular expression check box and use following regex

```
,\s*\n+(\s*\/\/.*\n)*\s*[\}\)\]]
```

Hope this helps